# Desktop doesn't open after selecting a different theme from the Gnome login screen

Tags: 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18. I hate the usual Ubuntu theme so I installed the Communitheme from the software center. But then after restarting Ubuntu to select the Communitheme from the Gnome Login screen (by clicking on the little settings icon) two things happen every time - first is that it doesn't accept the password the first time even if it's right, and secondly after accepting the password it doesn't show the desktop (it gets stuck at the login background showing and the mouse works).

I tried to find what the problem was and found it. The problem is that if I click on the settings icon, then the above mentioned two things happen. If I don't do anything and just log in normally, then it doesn't happen.

How do I change to Communitheme in this case?

Answer (score 1):

May be [gnome bug 1766137](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137). That includes a workaround to use while they are fixing it.

> WORKAROUND: After typing an incorrect password, click Cancel, then
>   click your name, then enter your password again.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! We like to see useful contents right here, the answers should not depend on external sites, see [answer]. I’ve quoted the important part of your link, please do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

what works for me is running `ctrl+alt+F4` and then `ctrl+alt+F1`.

It will take a few seconds, but after that, continue as normal.