# after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 everything destroyed

Tags: upgrade, system

and now after login to my account in Ubuntu nothing loaded! just a red screen I have! help me please. all my documents is in there

Comment: Can you move the mouse cursor after you try to login and you just have the solid login background? You may have the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029957/desktop-doesnt-open-after-selecting-a-different-theme-from-the-gnome-login-scre/1030621). The problem there is the desktop isn't visible after login. For me, I can shut down as in that post and reboot and it works (but problem happens occasionally)

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You may have Gnome default sign in instead of Unity. Click the gear next to `Sign In` button and select `Unity` before you press `Enter` after your password.